# How to use Stanford Core NLP in an eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, eclipse-plugin, stanford-nlp

I want to use Stanford Core NLP in an eclipse plugin project. There are a number of jar files which need to be included to use this NLP package.

1. One way to use them is to include the jar files as an eclipse plugin. However, only those jar files can be used which have OSGi metadata in their MANIFEST-MF file.
2. The next was to include jar files in the plugin itself. However, this method fails to detect the jar files.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?